# How to fix Bitmap failed to stabilize error on Silk Test

Tags: silktest

getting Bitmap exception on captureBitmap() method for desktop application in silktest workbench

```
With _desktop.FormsWindow("AppMainWindow")
    .CaptureBitmap("C:\Snapshots\ErrorImage.PNG")
    .PushButton("buttonOK").Click()         
End With
```

**Exception:**

```
Silk Test Workbench
Playback error in the .NET Script 'TestSuiteDriver':
SilkTest.Ntf.BitmapNotStableException:
Bitmap failed to stabilize.
```

added the below code in vb.net script.

```
Agent.SetOption(Options.BitmapMatchCount, 0)
Agent.SetOption(Options.BitmapMatchInterval,0)
Agent.SetOption(Options.BitmapMatchTimeout,0)
```

but still getting the exception.

Need to configure something in the Silk Test Workbench?

Answer (score 0):

I would increase the timeout to something larger and the match interval as well. That way it gives the Workbench more time to detect the bitmap. Setting them all to zero means it will check once and then stop.

Comment: For Agent options, tried with different values. But exception is not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

"SilkTest Open Agent" is a background process running locally when silk test
workbench tool is opened.

Stopped the already running open agent, and re-run the new Open Agent process and executed the script. It fixed the "BitmapNotStableException".